# Don't put your toy in the stairway

Tags: grammar

> "Don't put your toy in the stairway."
>
> "Don't put your toy in the stairs."

I told him not to put his toy in the stairs because others won't see it and might fell down.

Do they have different meaning?

Comment: It would be more idiomatic in AmEng to say "Don't put your toy **on** the stairs." "In the stairway" would mean in a common stairwell in a multi-unit dwelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many of your previous questions, the problem is not so much your choice or prepositions as your *word choice*.

Yes, you can *put* something *on* the stairs, but in this context it's not the *putting* that bothers you.  It's the *leaving*.  It's fine for your son to put his toy on the stairs as long as he doesn't *leave* it there for other people to *trip over*.

> Please don't **leave** your toy **on** the stairs.  Someone might **trip over** it and hurt themselves.